# Why general elliptic curve includes Neron $N$-gon?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

I’m studying generalized elliptic curves. I can understand that we have to consider the case of nodal cubic, to add cusps and get a proper modular curve or something like that. But where does Neron $N$-gon come from? Or what’s the relation between nodal cubic and Neron $N$-gon?

Thank you!

Comment: It appears from degeneration of elliptic curves. It is a classical result of Kodaira which classifies special fibers of an elliptic surface, and N-gon is one of them.

Comment: As a side information, see this interesting Habilitation thesis: http://www.maartenderickx.nl/articles/Proefschrift.pdf